# What does 'foreach(1..4)' mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops, syntax, foreach

In Perl, what does `foreach(1..4)` mean?  Specifically the two periods.  I've been having trouble finding an answer.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Comment: I've looked in the perl cookbook and on the API.  Just having some trouble getting used to the lingo of perl coming from python.

Comment: @Matt Just my advice on the OReilly cookbooks (I have a few, including the Perl and Python ones) - they can be great resources, but aren't super helpful while you're just starting to learn the language.

Comment: @admdrew Haha yes unfortunately I've been thrown into the language and have to work on a script that is much higher then my current understanding of the language.

Comment: This perlmonks post: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=78752 should help you learn to navigate Perl's docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, `1..4` produces `1 2 3 4` so you're looping through all the numbers from 1 to 4, assigning each value in turn to `$_`.

Comment: Also, when the list of a `foreach` loop is a single range operator, there's an optimization that avoids creating an actual list (so `foreach (1..1000000)` doesn't create a million-element list).

Answer (score 1):

`..` is one of the [Range Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

Answer (score 0):

It is known as the range operator.

It creates a range between the two operands...

Comment: In list context it is the range operator.  In scalar context it is the flip-flop operator, and works totally differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(1..4)
```

It means your loop runs from 1 to 4
or
creates a range between the two operands

Example equals to

```
my $min = 999;
foreach $item (1, 2, 3, 4)
{
$min = $item if $min > $item;
}
print "Min = $min\n";      # expects Min = 1
```